# Swagger UI setup with Express.Router()

Tags: reactjs, express, swagger, swagger-ui

i am trying to autogenerate api document with swagger. it works fine when i use express but it is not working when i use express.router()

Server.js

```
const app = express(express);
swaggerDoc(app);
endpoints(app);
```

endpoint.js

```
var routes = require('./routes.js');
const initialEndPoint=(app)=>{
         app.use('/api',routes);
}
```

swagger setup

```
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerJsdoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
const router = require('express').Router();
module.exports=(app)=>{
   // following line work 
   // app.use('/api-docs',swaggerUi.serve,swaggerUi.setup(specs));
  // with router its not working
    router.use('/api-doc',swaggerUi.serve);
   router.get('/api-doc',swaggerUi.setup(specs));
}
```

routes

```
var express = require('express')
  , router = express.Router();

    /**
     * @swagger
     * /hello1:
     *      get:
     *          description: This should return all users
     */
router.use('/1', (req,res)=>{ res.end('11111')});
  /**
     * @swagger
     * /hello2:
     *      get:
     *          description: This should return all users
     */
//not working    
//router.route('/2',(req,res)=>{ res.end('22222')});
router.route('/2')
.get((req,res)=>{ res.end('22222')});
```

I don't understand why swagger not working with router.route.